# HTACCESS How to redirect multiple protected url paths with specific substrings?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to protect multiple paths on my server from unauthorized access but I can only manage to do it for one url, if I add more it doesn't work anymore. Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _substring
RewriteRule (.*) www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

The example above works fine. But now I want to add more protected paths like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _substring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _substring2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _substring3
RewriteRule (.*) www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all.. what am I doing wrong?

The urls I'd like to redirect could look like this for example:

- mysite.com/username`_substring`/name_of_file
- mysite.com/`_substring2`/name_of_file
- mysite.com/`_substring3`/name_of_file

How can I redirect multiple different urls containing specific substrings to which no end-user should have access to?

Comment: Could you please confirm if `_substring` or, `_substring2` or `_substring3` are exact values(I mean not test values), if they are not then please do let us know if these substrings are similar in looking wise etc? Also do you want to look all substrings present in a single url OR there are 3 different urls where these can be there, it will be great if you could share sample urls eg--> from which uel to which url you want to redirect also.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. `_substring` could be either part of a folder name or the entire folder name for example it could be: `someuser_dir` where `_dir` = `_substring` or it could by `downloads` where `downloads` = `_substring`. I hope this clears up the question..?

Comment: Sorry if wasn't clear before. What I meant is if you have a url like `http://localhost:80/bla/_substring` OR `http://localhost:80/bla/_substring2` OR `http://localhost:80/bla/_substring3` which you want to redirect here? Could you please post sample of urls from which you want to redirect to another url, that could clear the things more IMHO.

Comment: example1: `www.mysite.com/user_substring`, example2: `www.mysite.com/_substring2`, example3: `www.mysite.com/_substring3` .. I hope this helps?

Comment: I've added examples in my question. I hope this makes it a little more clear now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, I believe we need a condition before applying https to urls. Please make sure your are clearing your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond HTTPS off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (member|directory|images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```